# Return rows based on multiple field search

Tags: php, sql, regex, laravel-5

Lets say I have a table with fields:

```
name, email, designation, city
```

What I want is that a user can search records by entering single word or multiple words in a single search box. eg. ABC abc@gmail.com

Right now I am using something like this:

```
$keywords = $request->get('search');
$searchValues = preg_split('/\s+/', $keywords, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

$users = DB::table('users')
                    ->select('name', 'email',  'designation', 'city')
                    ->where(function ($query) use($searchValues){

                        foreach ($searchValues as $value)
                        {
                            $query->orWhere('name', 'like', "%{$value}%")
                                  ->orWhere('email', 'like', "%{$value}%")
                                  ->orWhere('designation', 'like', "%{$value}%")
                                  ->orWhere('city', 'like', "%{$value}%");
                        }
            })->latest('users.created_at')->paginate($perPage);
```

This works but has a problem that it **returns all users** with **name 'ABC'** rather than returning only rows with **name='ABC'** and **email='abc@gmail.com'**

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: I am not familiar with php, but I think the problem lies in that you're using orWhere? think about a condition expression (name == 'abc' or email == 'bc@gmail.com'), when name == 'abc' is `True`, then will not check email == 'bc@gmail.com' is `True` or `False`, so the result is all the rows with name='ABC'. Change `or` to `and`, then you will get what you expect.

Comment: I don't know laravel but it seems like you should use `andWhere` for `name` and `email` instead of `orWhere` and isolate (take into parentheses) them

Comment: If I remove the Or then it will check each keyword with all columns and since name='ABC' would not appear in email or city column it will eventually return nothing for any keyword I enter

Comment: you should not use 'ABC' to check email, you gotta to find which string is name which string is email.

Comment: that's the actual problem. I want only a single search box to allow searching any column of the table otherwise the solution is very simple using WHERE AND

Comment: you have splitted the input, then you can get every string, then you can judge whether this string is email by '@', if the string contains '@', then this string is email.

Comment: ya but what about city, designation how do I judge that ?

Comment: I don't think this can be done in one sql statement, you can store the result in a container like vector(c++, php mush have something like vector), then in the loop you add the result in to the contianer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has a little known feature called `MATCH (column1,column2) AGAINST ('keyword1 keyword2' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` designed for full text searches. It resembles a google-like search where the keywords are matched to column values where the best match is the top result.

Beware that you have to clean up the search query first. Certain symbols are a no-no in a MATCH AGAINST. I wrote this function to clean it up and prepare the search query:

```
function returnMatchQuery($keyword)
{
    $keyword  = trim(str_replace(['+', '-', '~', '>', '<', '(', ')', '*', '´', '`'], ' ', $keyword));
    $keywords = collect(explode(' ', $keyword));
    $keywords = $keywords->map(function ($val)
    {
        return '+' . $val;
    });

    return implode(' ', $keywords->toArray());
}
```

In your main function:

```
$search_query = returnMatchQuery($keywords);
DB::table('users')->selectRaw("name,email,designation,city")
    ->whereRaw("MATCH (name,email,designation,city) AGAINST ('{$search_query}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")
    ->->paginate($perPage);
```

Note that `->latest('users.created_at')` is let out. You may or may not have to add it. The results may have more than 1 record. The first record is the best match.

For more information check [this MySQL page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: Its not a complete solution to my problem but still I can use it. thanks!